# What os difference websocket vs ssh-tunnel?

Tags: websocket, ssh-tunnel

we are replacing websocket instead of ssh-tunnel. May i know how websocket is better than ssh-tunnel?

Comment: what is difference between websocket vs ssh-tunnel?

Answer (score 4):

WebSocket is a protocol designed for 2-way real-time communication between browsers and servers to replace hacky solutions like long polling and XHR streaming.

SSH is a protocol designed for operating network services securely over an insecure network. Usually it's used for remote logins, file transfers, however it can be used for any protocol, however a few modifications need to be made.

The difference between them is, well, WebSocket is designed to be used for the browser and has support there. However, SSH is a more general protocol and can be used for more however it is not supported by browsers directly, but through proxies which bridge WebSocket to SSH.

There is nothing inherently "better" about WebSocket against SSH. It just depends on your use case, if you want to make a remote terminal or something for your sysadmins, use SSH. If you want to use it for, say, a real time chat in the browser, use WebSocket.